# Torque with single node, Mismatching protocol

Tags: torque

I'm trying configure Torque v6.1.1.1 on one server (-> one node, the server itself) with Ubuntu 14.04.
I install it with defauts parameters (configure). After building packages, I installed these modules : server, client and mom.
I configure like this :

- server_priv/nodes

`hostname`

- server_name

`hostname`

- mom_priv/config

`$pbsserver hostname 
 $logevent 20`

I get this error from mom_log:

```
LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Mismatching protocols. Expected protocol 4 but read reply for 0
```

from server_log

```
LOG_ERROR::tcp_connect_sockaddr, Failed when trying to open tcp connection - connect() failed [rc = -2] [addr = 127.0.1.1:15003]
```

I tried severals things like : give a name for mom in config file and add this name in /etc/hosts, replaced hostname by localhost without results.

How can i do for resolved it ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkanks a lot, i solved it by

- install v6.0.1
- run `./torque.setup localhost root`
- server_priv/nodes : `localhost`
- mom_priv/config : `$pbsserver <hostname>` and `$mom_host localhost`
- servername : `<hostname>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest killing the `pbs_server` and `pbs_mom` processes and then restarting them. You can check each one separately with `pbsnodes` and `momctl -d0`.

Comment: I have with this with pbsnodes `ubuntu
     state = down
     power_state = Running
     np = 1
     ntype = cluster
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003
` and this with momctl -d0 `Host: ubuntu/ubuntu   Version: 6.1.1.1   PID: 189950
Server[0]: ubuntu (127.0.1.1:15001)
  WARNING:  no messages received from server
  WARNING:  no messages sent to server
HomeDirectory:          /var/spool/torque/mom_priv
MOM active:             16 seconds
LogLevel:               100 (use SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2 to adjust)
NOTE:  no local jobs detected

diagnostics complete
` It'

Comment: If `hostname` and `hostname -f` don't return the same output, then you need to stop them both (`qterm` & `momctl -s`), put the long name into the server_name file, comment out the `$pbsserver` line, and then start everything back up.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the hostname to the short name. That entails 1) updating `/etc/hostname`, 2) running `hostname <new short name>`, and 3) adding the short name entry to `/etc/hosts`. (It may also require a restart of both `pbs_server` and `pbs_mom` services.(